# Elements seem to wrap when I position them relatively

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to position some elements in a particular structure, of which I've drawn up a quick structure as below.

[image]

Effectively it's a parent container with several divs as below.

I've tried a bunch of ways via css, but there's some behavior that I'm clearly unaware of that's stopping me from managing it.

```css
#parent-container {
      width: 300vw;
      height: 200vh;
      left: -100vw;
      top: 0;
      position: absolute;
}

.sub-container {
      border: 3px solid black;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
      position: relative;
}

#content1 {
      left: 100vw;
      top: 0;
}

#content2 {
      left: 200vw;
      top: 0;
}

#content3 {
      left: 0;
      top: 100vh;
}

#content4 {
      left: -100vw;
      top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-container">
  <div id="content1" class="sub-container"></div>
  <div id="content2" class="sub-container"></div>
  <div id="content3" class="sub-container"></div>
  <div id="content4" class="sub-container"></div>
</div>
```

This is what I've last tried and it's got some very weird behaviours including wrapping. I've not got much of an idea what to do here, would appreciate any help at all.

Comment: Positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Comment: can you use `flexbox`, or is important to use `position`?

Comment: @LaaouatniAnas flexbox is okay too, I'm only doing this because I'm unsure of how to run with flexbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An element having an `absolute` position is removed from the flow, and its location is determined `relative` to the closest parent with a `relative` position.

So the parent container should have a `relative` position, and the child container should have an `absolute` position, as seen in the example below, where I altered the dimension to make it easier to notice the outcome.

```css
#parent-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.sub-container {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

#content1 {
  left: 0px;
  top: 0;
}

#content2 {
  left: 100px;
  top: 0;
}

#content3 {
  left: 200px;
  top: 0;
}

#content4 {
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent-container">
  <div id="content1" class="sub-container"></div>
  <div id="content2" class="sub-container"></div>
  <div id="content3" class="sub-container"></div>
  <div id="content4" class="sub-container"></div>
</div>
```